# Change where pyodbc expects libodbc.2.dylib to live (changing default odbc file locations)

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

When importing pyodbc

```
❯ python
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/pcosta/Documents/test/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pcosta/Documents/test/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I know why this is happening, as I don't have `libodbc.2.dylib` in the expected location. The reason is I do not have permission to write to `/usr/local/`, so I have Homebrew installing into `~/.brew`. This mostly works fine. I am even able to get both `tsql` and `isql` working as expected by following the steps outlined here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Mac-OSX.

So I do have `libodbc.2.dylib`, it's just that it lives in `/Users/pcosta/.brew/lib`, not `/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib`.

The main questions is *can I get pyodbc to look for `libodbc.2.dylib` (and other associated files) in another directory?*

I have all the files needed and have configured them correctly, I just need to repoint pyodbc somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: This issue is also being discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/681).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks in part to guidance from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/681) I was able to come to some solution.

Assuming you have `brew install unixodbc`:

1. Add the following paths (to `.zshrc`, `.bashrc`, or `.bash_profile`):

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/Users/pcosta/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/lib $LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/pcosta/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/include $CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/Users/pcosta/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/lib/pkgconfig $PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

2. Run `pip install --no-binary pyodbc pyodbc` to bypass the binary and build yourself